# NPM Installation - npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, bower

I am facing lots of issues after cleaning up and setting the environment in other devices. Its not letting me build my project grunt build stuck after processing the images

```
npm  install
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #5: Expected object but got string
npm ERR! typeerror     at inflatableChild     (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:93:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at BB.each (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotValue (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:142:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
npm ERR! typeerror     at processImmediate (timers.js:638:19)
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\YouStable\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-30T00_58_00_673Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `node v6.11.2` with `npm v10.16.3`, I faced this issue too,
 
and was almost tempted to upgrade to the latest versions:(

The issue results from a somewhat corrupt `package-lock.json` file from which `npm install` tries to read/configure the dependency tree before any new installation.

[Best advice that I got](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18128#issuecomment-382705519) was to actually **delete the package-lock.json** file from the root folder. After then, I was able to `npm install` successfully.